# How to set my custom URL for product collection in Magento custom module?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have setup following page for product collection in custom module page which come from the following url as

```
http://localhost/magento/brand/htc
```

xml from frontend.xml file

```
<shop_index_pageview>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="shop/shop" name="testattrproduct" template="shop/product.phtml" />
            <block type="shop/shop" name="shop" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
              <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                  <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager" />
              </block>
              <action method="setColumnCount"><column_count>6</column_count></action>
              <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
              <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
              <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
              <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
              <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
              <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
              <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>     
            </block>              
      </reference>      
    </shop_index_pageview>
```

Using Routing i have set which module,controller,action to use.

```
<events>
        <controller_front_init_routers>
            <observers>
                <test_initRouter>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Test_Shop_Controller_Router</class>
                    <method>initController</method>
                </test_initRouter>
            </observers>
        </shop_initRouter>
        </events>
```

File from Controller/Router.php

```
            ...
            ...
    public function match(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request)
{  

        $front = $this->getFront(); 
    $identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');  
    if ($identifier) {
        $p = explode('/', $identifier);
    } else {
        $p = explode('/', $this->_getDefaultPath());
    }    
        ...
            ...
    if(substr('brand', 0, strlen('brand')) =='brand'){ 
        if($p[1] == '')
            {
                $action = "view";
                $param = $action;
            }
        else
            {
                $action = "pageview";
                $param = $p[1];
            }
        $request->setModuleName('shop')
            ->setControllerName('index')
            ->setActionName(trim($action, '/'));
        if($p[1] == '')
            $request->setParam('param', $param);
        else
            $request->setParam('identifier', $param);
        return true;
    } 
}       
            ...
            ...
```

From block file

```
...
    protected function _getProductCollection() {

        if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
            $_getCurrentAttrObj = $this->_selected_attribute;
            // d($_getCurrentAttrObj->getData());
            if($_getCurrentAttrObj){
                $_defConfigAttrId = Mage::getStoreConfig('shop_by_brand/all_brands_page_setup/attribute_list');
                $arg_attribute = Mage::helper("shop")->getAttributeNameById($_defConfigAttrId);
                $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getCollection('*')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
                $collection->addAttributeToFilter('test',12);
                Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);
                $this->_productCollection = $collection;
            }
        }
        return parent::_getProductCollection();
    }   
....
```

This comes as expected.I can list the product collection from product.phtml Here i can see the url like as  follows

```
> http://localhost/magento/shop/index/pageview/identifier/htc/?mode=list
```

Instead I need url in product collection as

```
> http://localhost/magento/brand/htc/?mode=list
```

How can i set/acheive routing url  in product collection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use overriding or rewriting in config.xml

```
 <global>
    <blocks>
      <shop>
        <class>Test_Shop_Block</class>
      </shop>
     <catalog>
        <rewrite>
          <product_list_toolbar>Test_Shop_Block_Product_List_Toolbar</product_list_toolbar>
        </rewrite>
      </catalog>      
    </blocks>
  </global>
```

And From Toolbar.php

```
class Test_Shop_Block_Product_List_Toolbar extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
{

    public function getPagerUrl($params=array())
    {
        $getDefaultUrl = new Magecart_Shopbyattribute_Block_Shop();
        $getDefaultUrlKeyForAttr = $getDefaultUrl->getDefaultUrlKeyForAttr();
        $_params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $identifier = $_params['identifier'];
        $urlParams = array();
        $urlParams['_current']  = false;
        $urlParams['_escape']   = true;
        $urlParams['_use_rewrite']   = true;
        $urlParams['_query']    = $params;

        return $this->getUrl($getDefaultUrlKeyForAttr.'/'.$identifier, $urlParams);
    }


}
```

That is it. Now the magento will use the url from getPagerUrl() function :)

Answer (score 0):

I think setting the controller's "frontName" to "brand" would be the easiest way to achieve this without using a custom router.

```
<routers>
        <Example>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Example</module>
                <frontName>Cool</frontName>
            </args>
        </Example>
 </routers>
```

But if the routing logic is more complex for your particular use case then you should define the router properly, not as an event observer.

```
<default>
    <web>
        <routers>
            <shop_router>
                <area>frontend</area>
                <class>Test_Shop_Controller_Router</class>
            </shop_router>
        </routers>
    </web>
</default>
```

Comment: Thanks,I have used the frontname setup in config.xml. This frontname will be dynamically come from admin config items :).so i used custom routing

Comment: What do you mean when you say the url is "coming". The router doesn't change the way URLs are built when they are created in the template. To test the router you need to manually type in that URL and the router should match it and set the correct controller/action.

Comment: As long as you have your own controller it's falls on you to implement product listing, filtering, sorting, grid-views etc. in your controller/block. The behavior doesn't get inherited automagically "passed down" or "inherited" from somewhere else.

Comment: Alongside the brand filter `$collection->addAttributeToFilter('test',12);` you'll have to add filtering, sorting based on the parameters you receive in the URL.

Comment: If you want to make use of the same functionality as the product-listing, you'll have to make your block extend the product-listing block and override its `_toHtml` method or some other method and add your brand filter to `$this->_productCollection` which already has a number of filters of its own (which handle the URL filtering, sorting etc.).